# What is a compound adjective for "chemical + colloidal"?

Tags: adjectives, compound-adjectives

I am trying to figure out what would be the correct compound adjective which I can use instead of "*chemical and colloidal*". I would expect it to be similar to "*physicochemical*". What are the rules of making such type of adjectives? I came across "*chemocolloidal*" and "*chemicolloidal*" but not sure which one is correct, if any. Also, do we need to use the *-al* suffix for "*colloid*"?
Will greatly appreciate your help and explanation.

Comment: What's so wrong with *chemical and colloidal* that you feel the need to make something up? In what way is it being used that makes a single word necessary? I don't think anybody would question the use of the multiple words. On the other hand, any of the single-word alternatives would be looked at strangely by someone.

Comment: Of the options you give, I would choose "chemicocolloidal". The "-al" makes it a definite adjective. It fits in with the general scheme of such adjectives, e.g. pyscho-logic-al, pharma-ceutic-al,

Comment: Not sure why you would want to use the two-fold adjective "chemical and colloidal". Why not simply "colloidal", with chemical being implicit? What do you intend "chemical and colloidal" to modify? // "Chemocolloidal" is an adjective. Perhaps it refers to chemistry taking place in a colloidal dispersion? When I googled it, I found no uses of it as a technical term. // "Chemicolloid" is a noun. I have no idea what it means. When I googled it, I found no uses of it as a technical term.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I would like to use it to emphasize the connection between chemical and colloidal properties: the dependence of chemical properties on colloidal properties and vice versa. So I am not sure which part is a modifier here. Also, one-word adjective might sound better in titles, for example, "Chemocolloidal properties of surface-active substances" versus "Chemical and colloidal properties of surface-active substances". It also would be nice to learn the rules behind making such compound adjectives. "Chemicocolloidal" is an option I would never think about before. Thanks!